# beacon detection in background even though app is closed

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

Hi i am developing an application with beacons i need to scan for beacons continuously even though app is closed. is there any cordova  plugin which is able to run in background, please suggest me sample applications tutorials

Comment: Are you sure you need the app to be continuously scanning for beacons in the background, or would having the app woken up after it comes close to beacons (e.g., to show a notification) be enough? The former is much more tricky to do (see responses below) and also much harder to get past the Apple review team.

Answer (score 1):

Background modes are only a partial answer. You need to have one of or both entries in Info.plist:

[image]

Then in some place in your code you need to ask for requestWhenInUseAuthorization or in your case requestAlwaysAuthorization. Then you need to handle this in location manager delegate. I'm doing it like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

        [self startMonitoringAllRegions];

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
```

So somewhere i'm asking to start monitoring for a beacon region then in this method I'm checking if I have permission from the user to do that if not I'm requesting if (the string from the plist will be displayed) if I have I'm starting updating user location.

Hope that will get you going :D

Comment: thank you, did you have working code of beacon monitoring even though app is removed from app switcher, and if any sample app r tutorials are there?......

Comment: My app is 'scanning' only when in use but when I tested it the icon was displaying on the lock screen. The idea is that you are registrating for region monitoring and iOS will 'wake' your app. But as I said i'm only monitoring regions when the application is in use :) As for tutorials any from the net i guess :)

Comment: that's okay i am unable to scan for beacons can you send me the link of tutorials

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with native iOS code, but not with Cordova.  When you say "scan" beacons, this usually means using the CLLocation ranging APIs, which provid updates of all visible beacons every second. In order to do this continuously in the background, you need to:

1. Add `location` as a background mode in your app's .plist filke in XCode as @hasan83 suggests.
2. Start a background thread to keep your app running in the background.
3. Request `requestAlwaysAuthorization` as @sloik suggests.

I wrote a [tutorial and reference app](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html) of how to do this.  The tutorial mentions this working only for 3 minutes, but with the background mode of location, the 3 minute restriction goes away.  Be aware that adding this background mode may make it more difficult to get your app approved for the AppStore.  Apple must approve of the reasons for this background use of location services.

The reason you can't do this with Cordova is because JavaScript must run to collect the beacon data returned by the ranging APIs.  This works in the foreground, but not in the background, because Cordova relies on a WebView being in the foreground to execute JavaScript code.  In the background, your custom code just cannot run.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, my requirement is when i ma near by any beacon i need to get a local notification and when i click on it app needs to open based on detected beacon major and minor values in need to populate the data

Comment: Understood.  While it should be possible to enhance Cordova to support this capability with a custom native plugin (or by augmenting the existing beacon plugin), unfortunately, the capability does not exist at present.

Answer (score 0):

> Allow UIBackgroundModes for location updates in the project plist
>   file.

Select the project at the left pane, then select **Capabilities** and expand the **Background Modes** list and select the **Location updates** option:

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, my requirement is when i ma near by any beacon i need to get a local notification and when i click on it app needs to open based on detected beacon major and minor values in need to populate the data

Answer (score 0):

Try [this plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE) for using iBeacons. There seem to be a few plugins for keeping apps running in the background, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode). I doubt you'll find both functions in the same plugin.